# How to solve "no newline at end of file" and "no matches found:...." issues in VS Code?

Tags: c++, json, vscode-extensions

Lately, I've been having some issues with VS Code (I'm not experienced in it)

I use it mostly for C++ and use the "Code Runner" extension to run my programmes...but it (almost) always has issues with building, more specifically, warnings such as "warning: no newline at end of file [-Wnewline-eof]" or "zsh:1: no matches found: *name of file i want to run*".

In order to solve the "no newline" warning, I've added to settings.json these: << "files.insertFinalNewline": true,
"files.trimFinalNewlines": true, >> , but it doesn't seem to solve the issue since I still get this warning.

About the "no matches found" issue..yeah..I haven't tried anything to solve this because I actually don't have any idea on how I should do it :(

I really hope that you guys can help me with these :)

I'm no expert at all in VS Code, as I've already said.
Hope I was clear :)

Comment: What you should probably do is stop relying on crutches provided by glorified text editors that pretend to be C++ compilers that understand C++ source code. C++ is very complicated and only a C++ compiler will fully understand C++ source. VS Code is not a C++ compiler. It'll get most things right, but if someone relies on their text editor's prompts to write C++ code, and their text editor gets it wrong, they're suddenly completely helpless, without their text editor's prompting. Someone who actually learns C++ and does not rely on their text editor's prompts won't have this problem.

Comment: ***How to solve "no newline at end of file"*** Add a blank line at the end of your cpp source file.

Comment: @Sam Varshavchik, thank u for the answer first of all, and second of all: what other text editors or IDE.s do u recommend for C++? Is CLion any good?

Comment: @drescherjm well...it worked )) thank u!..thought I needed to do something more complicated than this and that stopped me from trying it, to be honest

Comment: Although I primarily use msvc I learned long ago that gcc warned if you did not have a blank line at the end of the source file so I do that all the time now for over a decade.